# How to publish an extension like a private chrome web app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We developed an extension and published like a private app for the testing purposes before publishing to the webstore by choosing the option Private.

We followed the steps under this link
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2663860?hl=en

Now I log into webstore with my account and can't see that under "Your apps" section. Is there anyway we can trouble shoot?

How long does it take to show up under users accounts?

Comment: Is the account you logged-in included in the allowed users to view the Private app?

Comment: yes.. we gave access to all the users with our domain name